# Adobe Air - native process communication with exe fails

Tags: c++, process, air, exe, native

I'm struggling with Adobe Air native process communication. I'd like to pass an c++ exe  shellcommands stored at processArgs when started. The c++ program uses this arguments to choose device channel and symbolrate of an CAN-Bus-Adapter. The c program itself creates an json database for an html page. While the c program is processing i'd like to get some feedback of the program and if it exits adobe air should create a link for the html page with the function onExit. The c program uses standart  output of iostream lib ("cout", "cerr") to send messages to adobe air.

Adobe Air script:

```js
var process;
 
        function launchProcess()
        {
            if(air.NativeProcess.isSupported)
            {
                setupAndLaunch();
            }
            else
            {
                air.Introspector.Console.log("NativeProcess not supported.");
            }
        }
        
        function setupAndLaunch()
        {     
   var cpp_device = $( "#device option:selected" ).val();
   var cpp_channel= $("#channel option:selected").text();
   var cpp_symbolRate= $("#symbolRate option:selected").val();
   air.Introspector.Console.log("CHANNEL",cpp_channel);
   air.Introspector.Console.log("Device",cpp_device);
   air.Introspector.Console.log("Symbol Rate",cpp_symbolRate);
            var nativeProcessStartupInfo = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            var file = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("InteractiveDocumentation.exe");
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
            var processArgs = new air.Vector["<String>"]();
   processArgs.push(cpp_device);
   processArgs.push(cpp_channel);
   processArgs.push(cpp_symbolRate);
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
            process = new air.NativeProcess();
            process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            process.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
            process.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
            process.addEventListener(air.IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            process.addEventListener(air.IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
   process.addEventListener(air.NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        }
  
        function onOutputData(event)
        {
            air.Introspector.Console.log("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));   
        }
        
        function onErrorData(event)
        {
            air.Introspector.Console.log("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable)); 
        }
        
        function onExit(event)
        {
   air.Introspector.Console.log("Process exited with ",event.exitCode);
   $("#output").html("<a href=\"Soll.html\">Start</a>");
        }
        
        function onIOError(event)
        {
             air.Introspector.Console.log(event.toString());
        }
  
$(function()
{ 
  $("#start").click(function()
  { 
   air.Introspector.Console.log("START");
   launchProcess();
  });
});
```

the c program is quite long, and here i post only the main part

```js
int main( int argc, char *argv[])

 {
//! get shell commands for init
// echo shell commands
 for( int count = 0; count < argc; count++ )
 {
         cout << "  argv[" << count << "]   "
             << argv[count];
 }
// handle data
 intDevice = (int)(argv[1][0] - '0');
 intChannel = (int)(argv[2][0] - '0');
 intChannel -= 1;
 intSymbolRate = atoi(argv[3]);


//! class function calls
 useDll CanFunction;
 try
 {
  CanFunction.initProg();
  CanFunction.ecuScan();
  CanFunction.openSession();
  CanFunction.readECU();
  CanFunction.stopProg();
  return 0;
 }
//! exception handling
 catch(int faultNumber)
 {
      ....
    }
 }
```

First I used only the onExit listener and everything works fine. After I used start conditions adobe air only responses if i call no class functions except the CanFunction.initProg() and the onExit function was called but skipped the jQuery command to create the link. If I add the class function calls, the c program is called and the json database created but Adobe Air doesnt received any responses. The json database is still created. This confuses me.

My c program uses some *.dll files to communicate with the bus so i could imagine that it is a windows problem. But it is still weird. 
Has anybody an idea why adobe air communication doesnt work with my c program if i call my class functions or why the jQuery command is skipped? 
Or is there a better solution to call a c++ exe from adobe air?